# How do I stop my method running twice in python?

Tags: python

Code:

```py
import requests
from time import strftime, sleep

a = 20200422
b = 93

def getData(a,b):
    r = requests.get(
        f"https://www.examplesite.com/docs/doc-{str(a)}-testing-str{b}.pdf")
    if r.status_code == 200:
        with open(f"{b}.pdf", 'wb') as f:
            f.write(r.content)
            print(f"File Saved As {b}.pdf")
            retVal = True
            return retVal  
    else:
        print("[!] File Not Found")
        retVal = False
        return retVal

flag = True
i = 0

while flag:
    i += 1
    if(i == 1):
        retVal = True
    else:
        retVal = getData(a,b)
    if(retVal):
        sleep(2)
        a += 1
        b += 1
        getData(a,b)
    else:
        sleep(10)
        getData(a,b)
```

The output of this is:

```
File Saved As 94.pdf
File Saved As 94.pdf
File Saved As 95.pdf
File Saved As 95.pdf
[!] File Not Found
[!] File Not Found
```

How do I make it so if there is no new file on the website, I don't download it?

Comment: when i != 1 both else blocks are executed. So change your if/else logic according to what you are trying to do

Comment: I don't understand why you're calling `getData()` again when `retVal` is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the file is not found, the value of the flag is still True. So, a solution is: when the file is not found set the flag to false, so the getData() function will not be called again.
`

```
def getData(a,b):
    r = requests.get(
        f"https://www.examplesite.com/docs/doc-{str(a)}-testing-str{b}.pdf")
    if r.status_code == 200:
        with open(f"{b}.pdf", 'wb') as f:
            f.write(r.content)
            print(f"File Saved As {b}.pdf")
            retVal = True
            return retVal  
    else:
        print("[!] File Not Found")
        retVal = False
        flag= = False
        return retVal
```

`